# Get contents of a table cell without removing tags inside

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Beginner with Python here, I'm trying to create a script to retrieve data from a table and organize it in a dictionary.

The HTML structure looks like this :

```
 [...previous code]
 <table class="waffle" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
       <tr style='height:39px;'>
          <td class="s0" dir="ltr">Gold</td>
          <td class="freezebar-cell"></td>
          <td class="s1" dir="ltr">Johnny <span style="bold">M.</span></td>
       </tr>
       <tr style='height:39px;'>
          <td class="s0" dir="ltr">Silver</td>
          <td class="freezebar-cell"></td>
          <td class="s1" dir="ltr">Maria <span style="bold">R.</span></td>
       </tr>
 [rest of the code...]
```

My current script looks like this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

itemTypeList = [] # Create list of item types
itemContentList = [] # Create list of item contents

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("test/myfile.html"), "lxml") # Open the file

table_body = soup.find("tbody") # Find the table
rows = table_body.find_all("tr") # Find the rows

for row in rows: # For each row
    itemType = row.find_all("td")[0].text # Define the first cell as item type
    itemContent = row.find_all("td")[2] # Define the third cell as item content
    itemTypeList.append(itemType) # Add item type to the item types list
    itemContentList.append(itemContent) # Add item content to the item contents list

mailContent = {itemTypeList[i]: itemContentList[i] for i in range(len(itemTypeList))} # Create a dictionary with type and content for each item
```

Here's what I get with this script :

```
['Gold': <td class="s1" dir="ltr">Johnny <span style="bold">M.</span></td>, 'Silver': <td class="s1" dir="ltr">Maria <span style="bold">R.</span></td>]
```

I'd like to remove the `<td></td>` tag around my itemContent items but I can't use ".text" like I do on itemType because I need to keep the `<span style="bold">` tag to reuse it later in my code.

What's the best workaround to do this? I've been searching for the past three hours with no luck. Apparently `.unwrap()` could be useful there but when I add it to my code I get an error.

Thanks for reading this far!

Julien

Answer (score 0):

You can get the innerHTML using `element.decode_contents()`.

```
for row in rows: # For each row
    itemType = row.find_all("td")[0].text # Define the first cell as item type
    itemContent = row.find_all("td")[2] # Define the third cell as item content
    itemTypeList.append(itemType) # Add item type to the item types list
    itemContentList.append(itemContent.decode_contents()) # Add item content to the item contents list

mailContent = {itemTypeList[i]: itemContentList[i] for i in range(len(itemTypeList))} # Create a dictionary with type and content for each item
```

Output:

```
{'Gold': 'Johnny <span style="bold">M.</span>', 'Silver': 'Maria <span style="bold">R.</span>'}
```

Comment: Hi Mitchell, thank you, this works! Just a quick additional question before I mark the thread as solved, some of the rows contain blocks of text with more characters, and I see the '<br>' tags are converted to '\n<br/>',  apostrophes get a backslash before them and special characters disappear. How can I keep (or transform the text to) the initial formatting?

Comment: Hi Julien, the backslash printed before the single quotes is just a way how python interprets a string with quotes and doublequotes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65974985/get-contents-of-a-table-cell-without-removing-tags-inside/65975033?noredirect=1#comment116650338_65975033. Please open up a new question with a reproducible example for your other questions.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `row.contents`

```
mailContent = []

for row in rows:
    itemType = row.contents[1].text
    itemContent = row.contents[5]
    mailContent.append({
      itemType  : "{} {}".format(itemContent.text, itemContent.span)
    })

print(mailContent)
```

Comment: Hi uingtea, thanks for stopping by! I just tried your solution but it gives me an error : 'File "script.py", line 17, in <module>
    itemContent = row.contents[5]
IndexError: list index out of range'

Comment: check if `row.contents[5]` length greater than 6 or can you upload full html source to pastebin or other so I can check it